# Do while loop nested in for loop wont iterate

Tags: java

I need to enter `N` which is a number of numbers for which I need to see if they can be divided by 3. Afterwards I need to display what % of numbers from the `N` I can divide. Numbers need to go from 15 to 62 and they need to loop until I enter the right value each time, but they don't. Instead, they just repeat the for loop regardless of my input. Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("Enter N number of numbers");
    int N = TextIO.getlnInt();
    int number;
    int counterOfDivisible = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < N ; i++) {
        do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from the 15-62 span");
            number = TextIO.getlnInt();
        } while (number<15 && number>62);

        if(number%3==0)
            counterOfDivisible++;
    }

    System.out.println("% of numbers from the N that can be divided by 3 is " + (counterOfDivisible*100.0)/N + "%");
```

Comment: Ask yourself, "Can a number be both less than 15 AND greater than 62 at the same time?"

Comment: Have a look again at `number<15 && number>62`. That condition can never be true.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Can you provide sample input and expected output?

Comment: Yes yes, missed that one, quite silly of me, got blinded by the loop issue, even with this update tho, if i enter value of 1 instead of the value from the span, it should return and ask me to enter again, that is the main issue that worries me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`number` can never be `<15` *and* `>62` at the same time. Think about your condition.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the quick reply, first time here. Quite silly mistake on my behalf.

This seems to do the trick i was aiming for.

```
do {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from the 15-62 span");
            number = TextIO.getlnInt();
        } while (number < 15 || number > 62);
```